# Naive permutation algorithm that python generator function doesn't support

Tags: python, generator, permutation

guys. 
It seems like I don't really understand the concept of Python generator functions, because I haven't figured out mistake in this code that is supposed to produce all the permutations of the string characters.

For instance, this one is based on simple set expansion and it works

```
def permutations(seq):
    perm_set = set()

    def perm(cur_item_set, cur_str=''):
        if not cur_item_set:
            perm_set.add(cur_str)
        else:
            for item in cur_item_set:
                perm(cur_item_set - set(item), cur_str + item)

    perm(set(seq))

    for (i, item) in enumerate(perm_set):
        print(i + 1, item)

    permutations('abcdef')
```

Meanwhile, this code doesn't work: `list(g)` provides `[]`

```
def gen_perm(cur_item_set, cur_str=''):
    if not cur_item_set:
        yield cur_str
    else:
        for item in cur_item_set:
            gen_perm(cur_item_set - {item}, cur_str + item)

g = gen_perm(set('abcd'))
```

Comment: Are you using Python3.3 or higher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you recursively call `gen_perm()`, you don't do anything with the return value.

Try this, if `yield from` is available in your Python version (3.3 and above):

```
def gen_perm(cur_item_set, cur_str=''):
    if not cur_item_set:
        yield cur_str
    else:
        for item in cur_item_set:
            yield from gen_perm(cur_item_set - {item}, cur_str + item)

g = gen_perm(set('abcd'))
print (list(g))
```

Or this will work on all Python versions.

```
def gen_perm(cur_item_set, cur_str=''):
    if not cur_item_set:
        yield cur_str
    else:
        for item in cur_item_set:
            for item2 in gen_perm(cur_item_set - {item}, cur_str + item):
                yield item2

g = gen_perm(set('abcd'))
print (list(g))
```

Comment: It might be worth explicitly noting that the first snippet is for Python 3.X and the second works for both versions.

Comment: Thanks, @JaredGoguen !